# Generating all combinations of size 1 to n (bitsets)

Tags: python, combinations, bitset

There is a lot of quick methods on stack overflow that generate all the combination of bitsets of size k.

Ex:

```
combos(4,3) = {1110,1101,1011,0111}
```

However, is there a quick way to calculate all combos for sizes 1 to n?

Ex:

```
allCombos(4) = 
{
  1: {0001, 0010, 0100, 1000}
  2: {0011, 0101, 1001, 0110, 1010, 1100}
  3: {0111, 1011, 1101, 1110}
  4: {1111}
}
```

Of course, I can just call `combos(4, i)` for i from 1 to 4. However, I want to take advantage of the following fact:

For each bitset `X` in `combos(4, i)`, we can set exactly one bit from bitset `X` from 0 to 1.

For example, `0011` is in `combos(4,2)` which generates `{1011, 0111}` in `combos(4,3)` since the 1st and 2nd most significant bits are 0's.

EDIT: here is my current way of accomplishing this:

```
def combos(set_, k):
    return map(sum, itertools.combinations(set_, k)) # take combos of 1, 2, 4, 8 ... and the sums to get bitset back

def allCombos(n):
    ret = {}
    bitset = set([2**i for i in range(n)]) # generates 1, 2, 4, 8 ...
    for k in range(1,n+1):
        ret[k] = combos(bitset, k)
    return k
```

Comment: I honestly don't think your "shortcut" is particularly efficient.  For any particular element in "list `n`", there are `n` elements in "list `n-1`" that can have one bit set to give that element.  If you're using `itertools.combinations`, it's really efficient.

Comment: itertools.combinations requires a set as input. My input will be an integer (a bitset). Right now, I have to convert my bitset to an actual python set, call itertools.combinations and then convert that set back into a bitset. Too inefficient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70119046/itertools-combinations-on-bitset

Comment: @martineau.  I don't think this is a duplicate.  This user isn't trying to create subsets.  He wants numbers with that many bits set, which is a slightly different problem.

Comment: "quick way" is rather subjective - how quick is your current approach? What does the code for that current approach look like?

Comment: if you are looking on some  specific ordering, from `ì` to `ì+1`, then you asking to get the nodes between two consecutive levels. So rearrange the "combinations" using a tree structure

Comment: @Mortz I added what I am currently doing. It defeats the purpose of using bitsets (somewhere else in my code) when I have to convert them into sets of powers of 2, and use `itertools.combinations` to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

As Frank Yellin points out your "shortcut" is probably not really that helpful. The only way I think you could slightly improve the time of this calculation is to recognize that if we flip each bit in each bitset in `combos(n,i)` we get the bitset `combos(n,n-i)`. You could create a very simple and fast function that would take in a set of bitsets and return a set with the opposite bitset for each. For example if given `combos(4,1)` which is `{0001,0010,0100,1000}`, it would output `{1110,1101,1011,0111}` which is `combos(4,3)`. This would cut your runtime roughly in half.