# how to use itertools.combinations on a bitset (python)

Tags: python, combinations, bitset

I have a python integer that represents a bitset. How can I use itertools.combinations (or some other method) that will take an integer/bitset as input and produces all combinations of size k **without having to convert my bitset to a set as input for itertools.combinations.**

For example:

```
combos(01011, 2) -> {01010, 01001, 00011}
```

My code currently:

```
def combos(bitset, k):
    # for ith bit in bitset, if bit_i == 1, add 2**i to bitset_set
    for s in combinations(bitset_set, k):
        yield sum(s)
```

My code is time-consuming, I must convert my bitset to an actual set, perform the combinations, and then sum the sets to get my bitset back. I am trying to shave down on this time.

Comment: is your bitset literally a python int? ints aren't iterable so how are you calling `itertools.combinations` on it?

Comment: @rchome They aren't. They're using `bitset_set`. Left out the conversion code that's just described in the comment.

Comment: so to be clear, are you trying to avoid the conversion from `bitset` to `bitset_set`, which is a `set` object?

Comment: yes; bitset to bitset_set AND converting the results of `combinations` back to a bitset by calling `sum`

Comment: There's no way to use `itertools.combinations` directly for bit manipulations. You could modify the combinations code (or write your own recursive version) to compute the bit-sum incrementally, lowering the total time complexity to merely a constant multiple of the total number of combinations.

Comment: Is this still your traveling salesman thing? I get the feeling you keep asking [XY problems](https://xyproblem.info/) and you maybe shouldn't use k-combinations at all.

Comment: haha, it actually is a traveling salesman problem. Any suggestions on writing a solution w/o using k-combinations? I want to write the Dynamic Programming solution and pass a reference DP solution. Somehow, the reference DP solution is way faster than mine.

Comment: I suggest you ask about X then.

Comment: I think at this point, i'd have to just post my code and ask people for what parts are the slowest. Correctness is not the problem and I want to stick to writing a DP solution. Heuristics and other improvements that stray from a pure DP is not what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of processing each combination yourself with Python code in a generator, you could let Python's C code do it:

```
def combos(bitset, k):
    # for ith bit in bitset, if bit_i == 1, add 2**i to bitset_set
    return map(sum, combinations(bitset_set, k))
```

Comment: ah, still no way to avoid converting my bitset to an actual set (and vice versa)?

Comment: @Peabrain It doesn't need to be a set, but does need to be some iterable. In any case, why do you care about that?

Comment: My algorithm is using a lot of binary operations to speed up my algo. This is one part that I can't seem to find a bitwise operational algo to get the desired results.

Comment: @Peabrain I rather doubt that the conversion from bitset to bitset_set is what makes it slow.

Comment: I agree with @KellyBundy. @Peabrain I think if you have to use `itertools.combinations` and iterate over all results, the runtime will be dominated by the `O(n^min(k, n - k))` combinations rather than the bitset conversion.